# Angular - dynamic custom svgIcon just show the first icon from my menuList

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I'm trying to set svgIcons into `mat-icon` tag but angular shows the first svg icon `'home'` on `<mat-icon mat-list-icon svgIcon="{{ item.icon }}"></mat-icon>` from `*ngFor="let item of menuList"`.

I have next menuList at my typescript file:

```
menuList: MenuItem[] = [
  { name: this.text1, icon: 'home' }, // <- only shows this icon
  { name: this.text2, icon: 'user-check' },
  { name: this.text3, icon: 'users' },
  { name: this.text4, icon: 'briefcase' },
  { name: this.text5, icon: 'feather' },
  { name: this.text6, icon: 'eye' },
  { name: this.text7, icon: 'message-circle' },
  { name: this.text8, icon: 'settings' }
];
```

HTML:

```
<mat-drawer mode="side" opened class="example-drawer">
  <mat-nav-list>
    <mat-list-item (click)="onRowClicked(item)" *ngFor="let item of menuList">
      <mat-icon mat-list-icon svgIcon="{{ item.icon }}"></mat-icon>
      <h4 matLine>{{ item.name }}</h4>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-nav-list>
</mat-drawer>
```

and for now angular shows this list, only taking the first icon `home`, which is not what I hope to see:

[image]

definitely I'm doing something bad, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: mat-icon should be a child element of <button> or <a> element according to angular material guideline

Comment: One way to do it without using svgIcon is `<mat-icon mat-list-icon>{{ item.icon }}</mat-icon>`

Comment: If you use google icons works fine, the problem about icons .svg is when you have trying to use .svg custom in your angular project.

Comment: @JulioLemus did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Replace mat-icon line in HTML by this.

```
 <mat-icon mat-list-icon>{{item.icon}}</mat-icon>
```

Comment: If you use google icons works fine, the problem about icons .svg is when you have trying to use .svg custom in your angular project.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it fine, in my app I do it same as you and works.

*svgIcon*
is for custom icons, if you are using angular material icons just add icon name within element like this

```
<mat-icon mat-list-icon>item.icon</mat-icon>
```

In case you want to add custom icon could you provide more info? Console error, if you are using (and how) MatIconRegistry to register your custom icons...